# How to calculate the value of resistor R2?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, ohms-law

[image]

How to find the value of R2 in this circuit? If I1 is 8 mA in this case (I = I1 + I2) and then given 5 V over R2 and R3, 5 V/0.008 A = 625 Ω. Is this answer valid ?

Or is it 5 V/I = 2mA = 2.5 = 1/2.5 + 1/2.5 = 0.8 = 1/0.8 = 1.25 Ω.

I have made several different conclusions and I think R2 is 1.25 Ω.

Comment: what do you know about R1?

Comment: After R1 the voltage is 10 volts?

Comment: @MikeD How do you know that? Can you show us how you made this conclusion by editing your question?

Comment: I have made several different conclusions and I think the R2 is 1.25

Comment: (Question has been reopened, now that the OP has added their own attempt.)

Comment: "5 V/I = 2mA = 2.5" makes no sense. Tell us your thinking here please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only two things you need to know:

1. Ohms Law, \$V = I \times R\$.
2. All currents through a node sum to zero, \$I_{R1} + I_{R2} + I_{R3} = 0\$. (*)

You know the voltage across \$R2\$ (it's given in the question). You also know the currents \$I_{R1}\$ and \$I_{R3}\$.

With the info given, you can work out the current through \$R2\$. With the current and voltage both known, you can calculate the resistance.

Your first calculation, of \$R2 = 625\$ is therefore correct.

---

(*)Note that currents flowing into a node, and those flowing out have opposite sign, so consider \$I_{R1}\$ is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd process the problem, in order:

1. There's no ground shown. Pick a node that looks `good` to me and call it \$0\:\text{V}\$ (or ground, so to speak.) In this case:

[image]

2. Assign known node voltages (known with respect to the ground reference just assigned):

[image]

3. Now, at this point I can see that I know the voltage difference across \$R_1\$ is \$15\:\text{V}-5\:\text{V}=10\:\text{V}\$ and also know the current through it is \$10\:\text{mA}\$. So I can work out its resistance using Ohm's Law. The same is also true now for \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$, both of which will have \$5\:\text{V}-0\:\text{V}=5\:\text{V}\$ across them. (But you already knew that, of course.)
4. The only missing item is the current through \$R_2\$. But you already worked this out as \$10\:\text{mA}-2\:\text{mA}=8\:\text{mA}\$ (KCL.)

So everything needed to work out all three resistor values is known. Just apply Ohm's Law at this point and work out the values.

*(Those are the mental steps I'd likely take, anyway, if left to my own devices and not where a teacher/assignment requires some other methods to be applied.)*